# How can I use appropriate the lock mutex function, for three threads in C++?

Tags: c++, c, pthreads

I have a question about threads but I think that is difficult to explain, so be patient.

I have two pthreads in a QT/C++ program and one signal, Signal fills a buffer, One thread copies the buffer and one to process the buffer's data.

```
fill buffer1 ----Copy buffer1 to buffer2----process the buffer's 2 data
```

Signal's function:

```
void MainWindow::TcpData()
{
if(socket->bytesAvailable()>(DATA_LEN)) {
    QByteArray array = socket ->readAll();
    if(pthread_mutex_trylock(&data_mutex)==0)
    {
         if((p+array.size())<(MAX_TCP_BUFFER_SIZE+100))
         {   
                memcpy(BUFFER+p,array.data(),array.size());
                p+=array.size();
         }
         else {     
                p=0;
                memcpy(BUFFER,array.data(),array.size());
                p+=array.size();
              }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&data_mutex);

    }
}
}
```

Thread 1:

```
void *MainWindow::copyTCPdata() {
pthread_mutex_lock(&data_mutex);
while(1) {
    if(data_ready) {
   pthread_cond_wait(&data_cond,&data_mutex);
   continue;
   }
/* Move the last part of the previous buffer, that was not processed,
 * on the start of the new buffer. */
memcpy(data, data+DATA_LEN, (FULL_LEN-1)*4);
/* Read the new data. */
memcpy(data+(FULL_LEN-1)*4, BUFFER,DATA_LEN);
memcpy(BUFFER,BUFFER+DATA_LEN,p);
if(p>DATA_LEN) p=p-DATA_LEN;
data_ready = 1;      

pthread_cond_signal(&data_cond);

pthread_mutex_unlock(&data_mutex);

  } }
```

Thread 2:

```
void *MainWindow::processData {
   while(1) {

    if(!data_ready) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&data_cond,&data_mutex);
        continue;
    }
    data_ready = 0;
    pthread_cond_signal(&data_cond);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&data_mutex);
    detectSignal(data);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&data_mutex);


}
```

}

I think  am loosing data with this way, but the program is more stable, Can someone suggest me a better solution?

Comment: You have a brace mismatch in your program: two opening braces yet only one closing brace. And, I recommend using while(data_ready) { pthread_cond_wait(...); } instead of if(data_ready) { pthread_cond_wait(...); }

Comment: Post the **real** code.  From what I can see (which isn't much) this has more to do with predicate management than it does with threads. Whether you realize it or not, you have at least *two* predicate states chaining your thread dependency, which needs to be managed correctly.